# How to create a password field in xcode

Tags: xcode4

I am trying to make an iPhone App in which i will make user to login into their account.
For this i want userID and Password from the user. My question is how i can make a password
field in which whatever I enter will be shown as "*".

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for "`setSecureTextEntry`" on a "`UITextField`" object.

Also known as [the "`secureTextEntry`" property in the "`UITextInputTraits`" protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/secureTextEntry).

You can call this programatically via calling "`.secureTextEntry = YES`" on the "`UITextField`" object you want to be set for passwords.

You can also set it in Interface Builder (look for "Secure" checkbox in your text field Attributes inspector).  It looks like this:

[image: SecureAttributeForTextField]

And in newer version of Xcode:

[image: SecureAttributeForTextField In Newer Xcode]

Answer (score 1):

## Update for Xcode 12.2+

My opinion is programmatic declaration of properties are easier to toggle back and forth.

Programmatically in Swift 5:

```
myPasswordTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true
```